# Laravel pass value from query to with() function

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Here is my query:

```
$fix = Fixture::select('fixtures.*')
    ->whereDate('kickoff', '<', $date)
    ->with('competition')
    ->with('teamA')
    ->with(['teamA.standing' => function ($q) {
        $q->whereColumn('standings.competition_id', '=', {{here i want the competition_id from competitions or fixtures table}} );
    }])
    ->with('teamB')
    ->with(['teamB.standing' => function ($q) {
        $q->whereColumn('standings.competition_id', '=',  {{here i want the competition_id from competitions table or fixtures table}});
    }])->get();
```

Code from `Fixture` model:

```
public function teamA()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class,'team_a','id');;
}
public function teamB()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class,'team_b','id');;
}
```

Code from `Team` model:

```
public function standing()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Standing::class);;
}
```

Code from `Standing` model:

```
public function team(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}
public function competition()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Competition::class);
}
```

Can someone help me to get this done or if I am doing it wrong what's the correct way?

```
->with(['teamA.standing' => function ($q) {
    $q->whereColumn('standings.competition_id', '=', {{here i want the competition_id from competition table or fixtures table}} );
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: 
`Category::select('id', 'name')->whereHas('statuses', function($query) { $query(); })->with('courses')->get();`

Comment: I don't think this is what I want. I want Fixtures with teams, and teams with standings (team has many standings based on the competition it belongs to). I want team standings where standings.competition_id = fixtures.competition_id

Comment: If I have understood well, you should use `whereHas` twice.

Comment: could you give me an example. even if, how do i pass the value from  from running qry query to whereHas function..  $q->where('standings.competition_id', '**fixtures.competition_id**');, where fixtures.competition_id is from parent qry

Comment: `Fixture::all()->with('teams', function ($query) { $query->with('standings', function($query) { $query->where('query', query) } )})`
I hope it works